# Is it possible to use a "mailto" button in a native iOS HTML page?

Tags: html, ios, xcode

I have an IOS app that displays some hardcoded HTML pages... Is it possible to open the email program with a MailTo button ?

Comment: I believe any links with the mailto: protocol open the mail app. Surely you could just try this though.

Comment: Yeah .. Did Try that, but its not working ... I was wondering if there was something specific I needed to do in iOS to make it work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it using the below code, and the link was there, but the email App did not load when I clicked the link.  Nothing at all happened in-fact.  However, this was on the **simulator**.

**Update:  This did open the Mail App on an actual device.  So, yes, it does work!**

```
- (void)embedYouTubeWithVideoID:(NSString *)videoID {
    CGFloat w = webView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat h = webView.frame.size.height;
    NSString *ytUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/%@&version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&fs=1&hd=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showsearch=0", videoID];
    NSString *embed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html>\
                           <head>\
                               <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = %0.0f\"/>\
                           </head>\
                           <body style=\"background:transparent;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">\
                               <div>\
                                   <object width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\">\
                                       <param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\" />\
                                       <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\" />\
                                       <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" />\
                                       <param name=\"quality\" value=\"high\" />\
                                       <embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" />\
                                   </object>\
                               </div>\
                       <a href=\"mailto:test@example.com\">MAIL_TO_TEST</a>\
                           </body>\
                       </html>", w, w, h, ytUrlString, ytUrlString, w, h];
    [webView loadHTMLString:embed baseURL:nil];
}
```

[image: webview with mailto anchor tag]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `mailto:` HTML links that work. It will most likely not work on the **iOS Simulator**. Try it on your **device**.